# Best way to make a downloadable version of a Flash game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I already made a game with flash, and I want to provide an easy download for people that would rather play offline. Thing is, i use a folder whole structure to dynamically load content per level. Folder structure looks like this, not that it matters that much:

Game folder

- animations

  - anim1.swf
  - anim2.swf
- sounds

  - music1.mp3
  - soundeffect1.mp3
- levels

  - level1.lev
  - level2.lev
- myGame.swf

How should I go to distribute this? Should I just resort to make a zip file for the flash game and assume people know how to extract and open the swf? Is there any other way to port easily as an executable? Perhaps Adobe Air (not sure if this works though)?

Thanks, and please help!

Comment: If your game is structured this way, how have you been distributing it to places like Newgrounds and Kongregate? I would zip it all up and provide a Mac and Windows projector (via publish settings).

Comment: I havent been distributing to Newgrounds or Kongregate. Im using Adobe Flash Builder 4.0 so there is no main fla file which i can change its publish settings.

Answer (score 2):

Distributing a zip file is the only option if you really want that structure to prevail. Else,

- Embed all the resources in the main (myGame) swf & distribute it.
- Provide a html page for people  who do not have standalone flash player installed.

Embedding as a single file allows the browser to cache the single swf & allow the player to keep playing offline until cache is cleared. So user might not even need an explicit download.

Comment: +1 for embedding. It's *really* easy and lets you keep everything in one simple file - perfect for downloading or distribution. You can learn about the syntax here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ffb.html

Comment: Wouldnt embedding mean that every asset in the game would be loaded on the beginning? I have several levels which are a combination of xml and swf files. The game's size is 20mB, but the way its dynamically loading now, it's about 2MB initial size and then loads new stuff as the player unlocks new levels. For distribution might make sense, but that would either give me 2 versions:dist and web or just a big web version as well :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Flash Builder it is fairly straightforward to compile the application into a self-installing AIR executable (or DMG on a Mac). It is possible to include the AIR runtime which would avoid potential problems of the user not having the correct flash player for example.

An alternative to AIR would be to create a projector executable from inside the standalone Flash Player or from the Flash authoring environment.

Another option to using a zip file would be to use a free installer creator such as [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or [Nullsoft](http://nsis.sourceforge.net) on Windows, or Packager on Mac. Linux users are generally more tech savvy and so a tar would probably be well understood.

Comment: I cant seem to find a way to do it easily on Flash Builder. Cant add an output target or something. How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe AIR works wonderfully! I use it for my own project, and your project should transition over to it with little to no modification (any issues should show up in the Compiler Errors and Output). The only downside is that, past AIR 2, there isn't any Linux support.

The other option is obviously to create a standalone .SWF projector inside a zip or installer, but in my opinion, that isn't the sleekest way to deploy for desktop. The advantage of AIR over this is that it gives you access to additional desktop functions that Flash Player doesn't.

Comment: Im not sure how I can do this! Where do I configure my project's output for adobe air? Do i have to create a new air application and then import all the source files? I cant seem to find the steps necessary for this conversion on the internet! Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, okay. I'm assuming you're using Flash Professional CS5 or CS5.5. You're going to open your .fla up, and click on any blank area off of your canvas. View the Properties pane, and in the dropdown where it says "Flash 10.2", select Adobe Air 2.7.

Comment: Im actually using Adobe Flash Builder 4.0! The main swf is created via my Main.as file, which is a MovieClip essentially...

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to use that. I'd post a new question asking how to convert an Adobe Flash Builder project to Adobe AIR.