# Convert Adobe Flash Builder game to Air?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

I already made a game with flash builder 4, and I want to provide an easy download for people that would rather play offline. Thing is, i use a folder whole structure to dynamically load content per level. Folder structure looks like this, not that it matters that much:

Game folder

- animations

  - anim1.swf
  - anim2.swf
- sounds

  - music1.mp3
  - soundeffect1.mp3
- levels

  - level1.lev
  - level2.lev
- myGame.swf (generated from myGame.as)

How should I go to distribute this? Should I just resort to make a zip file for the flash game and assume people know how to extract and open the swf? Is there any other way to port easily as an executable? Perhaps Adobe Air (not sure if this works though)?

Thanks, and please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to make a downloadable version of a Flash game?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835153/best-way-to-make-a-downloadable-version-of-a-flash-game)

Comment: I posted this here as I was told to redirect my question to flash builder specific

Comment: Ah, all good, though it was probably meant that you should revise your current question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]You can do this with Adobe AIR. It allows you to include folders in the install directory of the project and load them at runtime, all with a single install.

### Update in response to comments

To convert a Flex project to an AIR project, you just need to change the project type in FlashBuilder or FlashDevelop to export to AIR. There may be a few specific API changes when you do this, but 99% of your code will copy over directly. Usually, there are no problems converting a web app to AIR, because AIR is a more permissive sandbox than the web. Moving from AIR to the web is not always possible, as AIR supports many features not enabled in the browser.

Then you have to select the appropriate export options for AIR to include your external resources folder.

Comment: Thanks, this is what im looking for, but, how do I convert my existing project to adobe air?

Comment: Air is almost identical to Flex/AS - just create a new air project and copy and paste source really.

Comment: On Flash Builder, I dont have this option enabled. http://i.imgur.com/tBzBi.png. On Flash Develop, I can only select project target to Flash 9, Flash 10 and Flash 10.1

Comment: Not sure why it isn't highlighted. It is for me, but Flash Builder is kind of junk, IMHO. Maybe take a look at the far more flexible (and free) IDE FlashDevelop. It not so picky about what you do with your files.

Comment: This remains greyed out for me. I believe that most of the time the correct answer is to make a new project and paste the source. It works 100% of the time.